# How to record a tab in chrome using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, video-capture

I am trying to open up muliple tabs and record everything in those tabs. Each tab will be recorded and saved as a video locally. I tried searching for ways to use extensions and use it but couldn't. I also tried using Chrome DevTools Protocol like this:

```
import pyppeteer
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

browser = await pyppeteer.connect(browserURL=driver.service.service_url)
cdp = await browser.create_cdp_session()

await cdp.send('Page.startScreencast', {
        'format': 'webm',
        'everyNthFrame': 1
    })
```

but it gives me this => `Unresolved attribute reference 'create_cdp_session' for class 'Browser'`. I couldn't solve either of these issues. Does someone how to solve any of these issues or even a better way to record a tab in selenium ?

Comment: I think you're mixing up Selenium and Puppeteer calls here... maybe try driver.create_cdp_session()?

Comment: nope, I tried it and same error but this time is WebDriver @pcalkins

Comment: for something like this you probably want Bidi, though I think they're still working on implementing everything: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/  They may have removed the old-style calls.

Comment: can you give an example @pcalkins

Comment: I can't... I've never used CDP or Bidi stuff myself.  I've seen some code posted here, but not for the Page.startScreencast bit... which looks to be an experimental option at this point... on top of that the Bidi W3C spec is still being worked out, so... https://w3c.github.io/webdriver-bidi/

Comment: If it's not possible to do this, you might consider just passing real-time pass/fail states for each action along with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to record te current tab in chrome using selenium. For do this the only way at this moment is using and managing from webdriver a extension in chrome that allow this task of recording the current tab.

But is a challenging task and probably you will need make modifications on that plugin for adapt it to your specific needs

In this artifact this task is done: https://github.com/AubaySpain/testmaker/

First there is a Chrome extension that record the current tab modified for my needs:
https://github.com/AubaySpain/testmaker/tree/master/core/src/recordVideoChomrePlugin

Then there is the class that manage this extension and start/stop/download the video:
https://github.com/AubaySpain/testmaker/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/github/jorge2m/testmaker/service/webdriver/maker/plugins/chrome/PluginSgreenRecorder.java